# Find all nearest points

Tags: algorithms, euclidean-geometry, computational-geometry

I have two sets:
$$P = \{p_1, p_2, ..., p_n\}$$
$$Q = \{q_1, q_2, ..., q_m\}$$

For each $p_i$ point I need to find all nearest points in $Q$.
I.e.,

$$p_i \rightarrow \{ q_{i_1}, q_{i_2}, ..., q_{i_k} \}, 1 \leq i \leq n$$

where $d(p_i, q_{i_j}) = min\{d(p_i, q_l) : q_l \in Q\}$.

I'm searching for the fastest algorithm to do this.
I'm working in two-dimensional euclidean space.
Would using k-D tree be efficient for this case? 
And another question,we can treat this problem as $n$ independent problems, and for each point from $P$ find nearest points in $Q$, but in wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#cite_note-14), in **All nearest neighbors** section it's written that n improved strategy would be an algorithm that exploits the information redundancy between these $n$ queries to produce a more efficient search. Where can I find such algorithm(any links maybe)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can reduce the size of candidates using the triangle inequality. Once you know distances to $p_1$ and the optimal distance $\min d(p_1, q_i)$, all points further away from $p_2$ than $d(p_1, p_2) + \min d(p_1, q_i)$ can be ignored.

Comment: @AlexR, I'm not sure I understand you. Could you please give a more detailed explanation? Or put a link, where can find the algorithm?

Comment: I'll write some pseudocode, but I can't guarantee optimality

Comment: @AlexR, ok, thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you check the answer and see if this is where you want to go?

Comment: @AlexR, I'm not sure, I think simple recursive divide and conquer approach is more preferable.

Comment: I'd be interested to see how you apply D&C here. Do you mind posting an answer of your own?

Comment: @AlexR, I'm sorry, but seems I was wrong :( Seems application of  D&C here is not possible. I've upvoted your answer, but I'm not going to use it, in my case performing a normal search is enough as in my case $|Q|$ is always small but $|P|$ is large.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest using the triangle inequality the other way around by building a similar matrix for $Q$ building a-priori candidate sets for each $q_i$ to save some effort. I may expand on that tonight when I'm home.

Comment: @AlexR, ok, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a somewhat efficient approach:

1. Build a matrix $P$ of distances, $P_{ij} = P_{ji} = d(p_i, p_j)$
2. Keep an array $d_i = \min_{q\in Q} d(p_i, q)$ and an array of lists
   $Q_i = \{q\in Q \mid d(p_i,q) = d_i\}$. We'll build these on-the-fly
3. For $i = 1$ perform the normal search.
4. For each $i \ge 2$:

   1. Find $\bar d = \min_{j = 1}^{i-1} P_{ij} + d_j$ and populate $d_i = \bar d$, $Q_i = Q_j$ with the minimizing $j$
   2. For each $q\in Q\setminus Q_i$ check if $d(p_i, q) \le d_i$

      - If equal, add $q$ to $Q_i$
      - If smaller, update $d_j$ and set $Q_j = \{q\}$ (won't happen too often)
      - If larger, do nothing

This will work especially good if some $p$ are clustered together so that they have the same nearest neighbors. If they are all random, it will at least help migitate *some* re-initialisations of the set $Q_i$ (wich should be the most expensive of all operations)